# Abstract Class Constructor: Possible to Inherit?

Tags: apex, class, polymorphism

I have tried the following:

```
public class OuterClass
{
    abstract class abstract AbstractInnerClass
    {
        final Object member;
        public Abstract InnerClass(Object member) { this.member = member; }
    }
    public class InnerClass extends AbstractInnerClass { }
}
```

However, this gives me a compile fail:

> Parent class has no 0-argument constructor for implicit construction

However I can change `InnerClass` to:

```
public InnerClass extends AbstractInnerClass
{
    public InnerClass(Object member) { super(member); }
}
```

Another change I can make indicates at least some constructors inherit:

```
public class AbstractInnerClass
{
    Object member;
    public AbstractInnerClass() { }
    public AbstractInnerClass(Object member) { this.member = member; }
}
```

Thing is, I do not care about the 0-argument constructor and don't foresee ever having any use for it. I tried to make an abstract constructor:

```
public class AbstractInnerClass
{
    Object member;
    public abstract AbstractInnerClass(Object member) { this.member = member; }
}
```

Unfortunately the above also results in a compile fail:

> Constructors cannot be abstract

**Is there no way to inherit constructors?**

Comment: Did you try using Super keyword ?You can use Super Keyword to inherit parent class constructor  https://developer.salesforce.com/docs/atlas.en-us.apexcode.meta/apexcode/apex_classes_keywords_super.htm

Comment: I clearly state in my question that I attempted that. `public InnerClass(Object member) { super(member); }` I am looking for a way to inherit the constructor without needing to redefine it.

Comment: Some relevant debate here: [Java Constructor Inheritance](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/1644317/java-constructor-inheritance).

Comment: @KeithC Except unlike in Java, Apex classes by default do not inherit from anything, which seems to be the main reasoning behind not inheriting constructors. There is no default inheritance in the way in Apex.

Comment: I'm a bit confused by what an abstract constructor would get you that the existing super keyword doesn't.  If you don't have an empty constructor in the base class then the inheritor must explicitly call super to get the right base constructor. What would the super keyword do if the base classes constructor was abstract? IMHO it's better to force the child class to explicitly indicate which base constructor it is using.

Comment: @DanielBallinger I guess that makes sense. But if you have four parallel signatures that just call their `super` equivalent, it's a little more verbose. That's all.

Comment: Can't be done :( i learned here: http://salesforce.stackexchange.com/q/24275/320

Comment: Thanks @bigassforce. That gets at what rankles me most about it, DRY. It is a much more detailed answer. I guess this question kind of is a dupe after all.

Answer (score 3):

If you define a non zero arguments constructor the default constructor (0 arguments) is not generated. For example if you have a class

```
public class Person {
    public String name { get; set; }

    public Person(String name) {
        this.name = name
    }
}
```

You can not create an instance of that class using default constructor like:

```
Person foo = new Person();
```

You will always get `Constructor not defined: [Person].<Constructor>()` error. If you would like to be able to create instances of your class using default and custom constructors you need to define 0 arguments constructor by yourself. And then in the child classes 0 arguments constructor will we called at the very beginning if you don't specify which parent constructor should be used (eg. `super` keyword).

In other words: 0-argument constructor inherits by default. If you want to inherit (execute) functionality from a constructor with arguments, **you need to manually call parent constructor from child constructor.**

Comment: I don't want to use the 0-argument constructor in any of my classes. This answer does not respond to what I'm asking.

Comment: Updated the answer. Now it should be clear.