# standard controller | incorrect signature | extending classes

Tags: apex, standardcontroller

I have:

```
public virtual classA{
    public classA(ApexPages.StandardController controller){}
}

 public virtual classA_Test extends classA{
     classA_Test(){}
 }

 Error in classA_Test: Method does not exist or incorrect signature: [classA].<Constructor>()

 IDE: Force.com
```

What is the problem here?

Answer (score 5):

When you define a constructor that takes parameters, the default `0-argument` constructor is lost.

When you instantiate `classA_Test`, it implicitly calls the `super()` constructor, which no longer exists. If you want to avoid this behavior, you need to call a different constructor that is defined, e.g.:

```
virtual class Vehicle
{
    Vehicle(ApexPages.StandardController controller) { /*do stuff*/ }
}
class MagicCarpet extends Vehicle
{
    MagicCarpet() { super(new ApexPages.StandardController()); }
}
```

Side note, you cannot inherit constructors. See: [Inheriting non-implicit constructors on Apex classes](https://salesforce.stackexchange.com/questions/24275/inheriting-non-implicit-constructors-on-apex-classes).

Comment: RESULT: Constructor not defined: [ApexPages.StandardController].<Constructor>()     in the MagicCarpet class

Comment: Yeah I mean it doesn't actually make sense to set it up the way you have it. Why are you creating an `extension` when you don't have a `controller`? What are you trying to accomplish?